# Clase Persona con atributo que es un array de la clase Mail

Tags: array, typescript, diseño-de-clases

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio y no consigo como declarar y acceder a un elemento.

Tengo 4 clases; `Persona`, `Telefono`, `Dirección` y `Mail`. Cada una en un archivo diferente y un archivo *main.ts* desde el que creo instancias de las clases creadas, que importo.

`Persona`, tiene unos atributos que son `nombre`, `apellidos`, `dni` , `mails`, `direcciones`, `telefonos`.

Estos tres últimos son arrays de cada una de sus correspondientes clases, es decir, una `persona` puede tener más de un `email`, más de un `telefono` y más de una `direccion` que se almacenan en un array.

Mi duda es en la llamada al *constructor*, en la creación de la instancia `Persona`, etc. ¿Cómo se hace?

Lo he intentado de varias formas: (De momento lo estoy haciendo para mails y después añado los telefonos y las direcciones por eso no aparecen)

Archivo **persona.ts**

```
export class Persona {
        _nombre: string;
        _apellidos: string;
        _dni: string;
        _cumpleaños: string;
        _color_favorito: string;
        _sexo: string;
       // _direcciones: Direccion[] ;
        _mails: Mail[];
        //_telefonos:Telefono[];
        _notas: string ;
        constructor(a:string, b:string,    
            d: string, e: string, f: string, g:string, i:Mail[] , k: string) {
              this._nombre = a;
              this._apellidos = b;
              this._dni = d;
              this._cumpleaños = e;
              this._color_favorito = f;
              this._sexo = g;
             // this._direcciones = Direccion[];
              this._mails = [];
             // this._telefonos = telefonos;
              this._notas = k;
        }
    
    //getter y setter nombre
    public get_nombre() {
      return this._nombre;
    }
    public set_nombre(value:string) {
      this._nombre = value;
    }
      
    //getter y setter apellidos
    public get_apellidos() {
      return this._apellidos;
    }
    public set_apellidos(value:string) {
      this._apellidos = value;
    }
    
    //getter y setter edad
    /*   get_edad() {
      return this._edad;
    }
    set_edad(value:string) {
      this._edad = value;
    } */
    
    //getter y setter dni
    public get_dni() {
      return this._dni;
    }
    public set_dni(value:string) {
      this._dni = value;
    }
    //getter y setter cumpleaños
    public get_cumpleaños() {
      return this._cumpleaños;
    }
      
    public set_cumpleaños(value:string) {
      this._cumpleaños = value;
    }
    
    //getter y setter color_favorito
    public get_color_favorito() {
      return this._color_favorito;
    }
      
    public set_color_favorito(value:string) {
      this._color_favorito = value;
    }   
     
    //getter y setter sexo 
    public get_sexo() {
      return this._sexo;
    }
    
    public set_sexo(value:string) {
      this._sexo = value;
    }
    
     
    
    //getter y setter notas 
    public get_notas() {
        return this._notas;
        }
    public set_notas(value:string) {
        this._notas = value;
      }
      
    
      
    //getter y setter mails 
    public get_mails() {
    return this._mails;
    }
```

> ESTE ES UN INTENTO(ME SALE ERROR)

```
    /* public set_mails(t:string, d:string) {
    var m = new Mail(t,d);
    this._mails.push = m;
    } */
```

Archivo **mail.ts**

```
export class Mail {
    private _tipo: string;
    private _direccion: string;
    constructor(a: string, b: string) 
    {
        this._tipo = a;
        this._direccion= b;
    }

 //getter y setter tipo
public get_tipo():string{
    return this._tipo;
}
public set_tipo(value:string) {
     this._tipo = value;
} 

//getter y setter direccion
public get_direccion():string{
    return this._direccion;
}
public set_direccion(value:string) {
     this._direccion = value;
} 
public mostrarMail(): void{
    console.log(this._tipo, this._direccion );
}

}
```

Archivo **main.ts**

```
//creo varias instancias de la clase Persona

    var persona1 = new Persona("Martín", "Bueno", "44215459-X", "20-08-1973","verde", "Mujer",[], "nota1");
```

¿Cómo añado el array de objetos de la clase `Mail` a una instancia de la clase `Persona`?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Gracias a todos!  Vuelvo al ataque...  He modificado el programa, no tengo errores pero no consigo ver los elementos del array mails. Este es mi codigo

```
fichero persona.js

public addMail(m: Mail) {
  this._mails.push(m); 
}
public listMail(){
  console.log('A continuación se muestran las direcciones de los correos dentro del array mails');
  for(let i in this._mails){
    
    console.log(this._mails[i]); 
  }
}


Fichero main.js

//creo varias instancias de la clase Mail

var mail1 = new Mail("trabajo", "alejandra@gmail.com");
var mail2 = new Mail("personal", "Bartolo1@gmail.com"); 
var mail3 = new Mail("trabajo", "rocky3@hotmail.com");


//Creo una instancia de persona pero el campo mail solo he puesto []

var persona1 = new Persona("Martín", "Bueno", "44215459-X", "20-08-1973","verde", "Mujer",[], "nota1");

//Introduzco los email dentro de un array para el objeto persona1

persona1.addMail(mail1);
persona1.addMail(mail2);
persona1.addMail(mail3);

persona1.set_mails(persona1._mails); 
 
//Recorro el array mails 

persona1.listMail;



Pero no veo los datos del email
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asignar un array, que antes tendrás que haber construido:

```
    //getter y setter mails 
    public get_mails() {
      return this._mails;
    }
    
    public set_mails(value:Mail[]) {
      this._mails = value;
    }
```

Para construir ese email haces un código similar al que ponias en el setter,,, un bucle que vaya añadiendo emails.

Comment: Buenos días! Gracias por contestar. He puesto la función indicada pero me sale error la he cambiado el orden  public set_mails(value:Mail[]) {
    this._mails = value;
    }  parece que ahora no me sale error. Pero ...¿En el constructor entonces...que tengo que poner y cuando hago la instancia, como pongo los valores del email ...separados por comas, o tengo que quitar del constructor el array _this._mails y usar su setter antes de instanciar a la clase Persona.  Gracias

Comment: No conozco la sintaxis, corrijo el error que me indicas. Basicamente, cuando crees una instancia de Persona lo haras llamando a su constructor y como te hace falta un Mail[], tendras que haberlo creado antes, es decir, declarar una variable de tipo Mail[] a la que iras añadiendo nuevas instancias de tipo Mail. Cuando tengas el array completo, lo podrás usar en el constructor de Persona... lo mismo con direcciones y telefonos.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento 3 detalles:

- El método `push` no funciona como lo has intentado.
- Javascript/Typescript usa setters y getters de un modo distinto a Java o C#.
- El constructor y las declaraciones de las propiedades de la clase se mueden simplificar, Typescript asume que cualquier parámetro marcado como `private` en el constructor es una propiedad privada de la clase, con lo que no tienes que declararla ni asignarla, lo hace automáticamente. Con lo que tu código podría ser algo como:

```
export class Persona {

  constructor(private _nombre: string, private _apellidos: string, 
    private _dni: string, private _cumpleanyos: string, private _color_favorito: string,
     private _sexo: string, private _mails: Mail[], private _notas: string) { }

  get nombre() : string {
    return this._nombre;
  }
  set nombre(value: string) {
    this._nombre = value;
  }

  // ... resto de setters y getters

  addMail(m: Mail) {
    this._mails.push(m); 
  }

  set mails(list: Mail[]) {
    this._mails = list;
  }
}
```